# After inheriting a function how to give it more parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, parameters

I inherited a `student` class for my `masters_student` class and and all the functions are working as expected but I want to give my `masters_student` class another parameter called `Age`.

How could I do that?

```
class masters_student(student , age):
    self.age = age
        def qualify(self):
            if self.Gpa > 3.0 :
                print("You qualify for the masters Programme")
            else:
                print("you dont qualify for Masters programme")
```

Then it shows a error

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.Gpa = Gpa
        self.loan = loan

    def On_honour_roll(self):
        if self.Gpa >= 3.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class masters_student(student):
    def qualify(self):
        if self.Gpa > 3.0 :
            print("You qualify for the masters Programme")
        else:
             print("you dont qualify for Masters programme")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on [https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/][super].

You need to tell python how to instantiate you children class following parent one.

```
class master_student(student):

def __init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan, age):
    super(student, self).__init__(name, major, Gpa, loan)
    self.age = age
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to get our terminology correct. I don't see where you are taking an existing function that you are inheriting and then redefining it to have additional parameters. When you code:

`class masters_student(student , age):`

You are specifying multiple inheritance, that is, you are saying that class `masters_student` inherits from both class `student` and from class `age`. But then on the next line you code:

```
    self.age = age
```

which does not make too much sense.

It seems that what you are trying to do is add to your new class, `masters_student`, an additional *data attribute* named `age`. I can't even be sure of that because I never see in your question any code that references `age`; I would have thought that it would be used in method `qualify`. But assuming that is your intent, there are several ways of doing this depending on whether you are running Python 3 or Python 2. The simplest way, which works on either Python 2 or Python 3 would be:

```
class masters_student(student):
    def __init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan, age):
        student.__init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan) # initialize the base class
        self.age = age
```

If you are running Python 3, you can also code:

```
class masters_student(student):
    def __init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan, age):
        super().__init__(name, major, Gpa, loan) # initialize the base class
        self.age = age
```

If you are running Python 2 (or Python 3), you can also code:

```
class masters_student(student):
    def __init__(self, name, major, Gpa, loan, age):
        super(masters_student, self).__init__(name, major, Gpa, loan) # initialize the base class
        self.age = age
```

But, you must ensure that your base class, `student` in this case, inherits from class `object`:

```
class student(object):
```

When you use `super()` to initialize base classes, the base classes, too, must use `super()` to initialize their base and sibling classes.